# Trying to expand a JSON but have each property has its own row in a postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to solve this issue for couple of days now but I still can't figure out this problem:

If I have a postgresql table:

```
| index    | json_data                           |
| -------- | --------                            |
| 1        | {age:45, name: tom, food: burger}   |
| 2        | {age:34, name: jack, food: steak}   |
```

What is the correct way of displaying the information like:

```
| index    | json_data                           |
| -------- | --------                            |
| 1        | {age:45}                            |
| 1        | {name: tom}                         |
| 1        | {food: burger}                      |
| 2        | {age:34}                            |
| 2        | {name: jack}                        |
| 2        | {food: steak}                       |
```

I have tried various method of dividing the json into separate columns but never successfully into separate rows.

Comment: then show us what you trued and which error occurs

Comment: Please note that your example's  `json_data` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A [lateral subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) will do the job.

```sql
select index, l.json_data 
from the_table t, lateral 
(
  select jsonb_build_object(key, value) as json_data
  from jsonb_each(t.json_data)
) as l;
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/veP2gvKmYPDB3To6vTHgpv/1)